# Gzip mistake with directory

Tags: linux, gzip

I accidently `gzip -rv directory` and now all individual files is in .gz format.  How do I undo this and gunzip all .gz files within the `directory`?

And how do I just gzip this whole directory?

I tried `gunzip directory/*.gz` but only gunzip the files in directory/ it doesn't gunzip directory beyond "directory".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To unzip your files, do the following:

```
find /yourdirectory -name *gz | xargs gunzip
```

This will unzip all files with the name *.gz `find` can find under the directory `/yourdirectory`.

For gzipping a whole directory, you need a `tar` container, as gzip can only compress individual files:

```
tar czvf archive.tgz /yourdirectory
```

If you want the (much slower but much more effective) bzip2 compression, use the `j` instead the `z` parameter:

```
tar cjvf archive.tbz2 /yourdirectory
```

Both commands will create a compressed archive, there is no need to do an additional compression step afterwards.

Comment: What command do you use exactly?

Comment: sorry my bad spelling mistake. it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
gzip -d -r directory
```

Answer (score -3):

Tar the directory first with `tar -cf myarchive.tar myarchive/`and compress it afterwards with `gzip myarchive.tar`.

You can unpack this afterwards with `tar -xvf myarchive.tar.gz` with newer versions of tar. With older versions you should add use `-xvzf` instead

Comment: Is there a way to undo all the .gz file?

Comment: Switch into the directory and type `gunzip *`.

Comment: The additional gzip step is unnecessary, and `find` exist.

Comment: Certainly you can add a pipe to run it in one line, however I fail to see why you would downrate my reply as it is totally correct and a valid reply to one of Macas questions.

Comment: It's for the recommendation to manually switch into the directory and do a gunzip. That's what the OP already did and wanted to avoid to do recursively.